# How to add data frames to a list and name them from a user written function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, functional-programming

I think I can ask this question without explaining the details of why I am doing it, lets try:
I am writing a function, part of what it does is create a data frame called `x`. I have a list that I would like to store this data frame in called `Subsets`. I can get the function to place `x` within `subsets` using this code:

```r
Subsets <- append(Subsets, list(x))#adds x to Subsets
```

This is great, but the purpose of having the list `Subsets` is to store multiple data frames (i.e., the function will be used for multiple `x`s, and this data frame for each `x` will be neatly stored in the list object `Subsets`). Naturally, I want to name this data frame something unique every time I use it for a different `x`. The naming convention I want to use can be extracted from information within the data frame `x`. I want to paste the values in `x[1,1]` and `x[1,6]` (which are columns that denote the unique location and id of each `x`) and use this to name the data frame stored within the list `Subsets`. 
I can (externally, outside the function) give make a new data frame from x with the name I want using `assign(paste0(x[1,1],x[1,6]),x)`
but when I try to combine these to make that the name of the data frame within a list, I cant get it to work:

```r
#the word in x[1,1] is NY and the word in x[1,6] is 1 
#so the name of the object within the list is supposed to become NY1
Subsets <- append(Subsets, list(assign(paste0(x[1,1],x[1,6]),x),)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to create a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list with an element named according to `paste0(x[1,1],x[1,6])`.  What `assign` does is create an object with that name.
This code should do what you want:

```
newlist <- list(x)
names(newlist) <- paste0(x[1,1],x[1,6])
Subsets <- c(Subsets, newlist)
```